# How do you grab all of the entries of a JList?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have the following objects accessible (plus many others which don't seem to be relevant to the question at this time).

Objects:

```
listModel = new DefaultListModel();
inputField = new JTextField(10);
addButton = new JButton("+");
usernameList = new JList(listModel)
```

The ActionListener for the 'addButton':

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   System.out.println("addButton clicked!");

   Variables.username = inputField.getText();
   System.out.println("Username now: " + Variables.username);
   listModel.addElement(Variables.username);
   inputField.setText(null);

}
```

At the moment, the 'addButton' grabs the input from the JTextField (inputField) and adds it to the listModel, and updates the JList (usernameList) with the new string. What I need to do now is take each element and either add each element to a different element within a pre-declared string array. How would I accomplish grabbing all of the elements passed to the JList?

Answer (score 1):

`ListModel model = usernameList.getModel();
 for(int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
   //do something
 }`